# Customized search on web and displaying result

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

On my lotus domino web application, I have customized search form where user can enter criteria (around 10 criteria ) is there, now what I would like to do is that I would like to throw the result to another page/form using html.

But my concern is that I would like to access div elements on the output form/page and I am not sure if I can do it Web query save agent of search form.

Basically what I wanted to do is I will compose html in the WQS agent and assign that HTML to div of the output search form. but I am not sure how to access div element of the another form using WQS agent of the current form.

I can display result in the same form but question would remain again how to access div element in the WQS agent of Lotusscript.

using document context we can access the field of the currrent document submitted but not sure about div element.

Please asssist

Answer (score 0):

In short, all you can do in a WQS is to spit out a stream of text (which may or may not be HTML) from the server to the browser.  So I think you have a couple of options:

1. In your template HTML, add a placeholder where your `<div>` is and do a replace() (replace the placeholder with the HTML you want to appear in that div) before sending out the HTML to the browser, or
2. Output enough JavaScript and/or JQuery and/or whatever so that the div is updated by the client after the document is loaded.  Of course there's no guarantee that will happen though.

Another approach is just to create a Notes document with computed fields and/or computed text.  In this case you don't think of updating the "div" as updating an HTML div, you're updating computed text on a Notes form.  When you return the document to the browser as a document instead of messing with a WQS agent.

I suppose your WQS agent could also potentially send out just JavaScript to update another page, but to me that smacks of a cross-site scripting attack.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some REST here. Basically submit the search form to a REST service, collect the results and render them as needed.